# Origin of "good'o"

Tags: idioms, british-english, australian-english

Where did the Autralian or British expression *good'o* come from? What is the *'o* part related to?

Comment: The dictionary I looked at shows this as a variation of "good-oh". The phrase just seems to be two interjections (good and oh) put together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OED has a long note on the ‘-o’ suffix. ‘Good-o’ seems to have derived from the practice of attaching ‘-o’ to other words to form conventional cries and refrains, a practice which is attested from late Middle English. ‘Good-o’, however, makes its apperance only in 1916.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be linked to colonial territories in West Africa. West Africans especially Nigerians have the culture of adding -O to words or phrases especially for emphasis on excitement, or a warning.

Comment: Any authoritative references to support this theory?